# How to merge the unlocated partition(previously installed linux) with the windows partitions?

Tags: windows-10, partitioning

I previously had two OS on my system - Ubuntu14.04 and Windows 10. Now I have formatted the Ubuntu one. Now the Windows 10 shows the unlocated space for that 30GB (space given to ubuntu). I want to merge that space "AGAIN" back to the same drive from where I fetched it from (in my case C:  drive). But its not showing the option of extend volume in any of the drives. What I am supposed to do?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: If your question is how to get Windows to extend the partition you'll probably want to change the tags away from the Linux side (since that's gone) to the Windows side

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Super User! It would be helpful if you included screenshots of the disk manager (or similar utility that you may be using) showing the lacking option. That information would help us identify the answer more quickly. For more information, have a look at [How to Ask](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)